# Interpolating time series wind data using correlation

Tags: r, time-series, correlation, python, interpolation

Is there a way to use correlation to interpolate missing data?

I know the wind speed in 6 locations every hour. This shows the correlation between the separate locations. [Hourly Data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100778374/Wind%20Data/5MinuteData_CWP_Capacity.csv)

I know the wind speed in one of the locations every 5 minutes.  [5 Min Data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100778374/Wind%20Data/Wind_Locations.csv)

Is there a way to use this information to create 5 minute wind speed information for all locations?

I have been using Python to analyze my data so far but can use R as well, just less familiar with R.